# 403 Forbidden message from API gateway when using Lambda Authenticator

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a proxy VPV link integration set up on api gateway. I am using custom lambda authentication which returns a grant payload with an implicit allow or deny. I have added a context keyword in the return response whose payload I use to map values in the http headers in the integration request i.e

header_data mapped to context.authorizer.header_data

This works as long as the context payload size doesn't increase 35 characters. In all the AWS Api gateway documentation that I've read, the maximum size of lambda payload is 6 mb and my return payload is a few bytes. If I increase from 35 characters it starts giving forbidden 403 response and doesn't reach my vpc link integration.

I need to pass two UUIDs in the headers that exceed 35 character limit.

I tried breaking the header into multiple key values and mapped them separately.
I tried to not use non-alphanumeric characters.